# Stepper material : using stepper.reset() inside typescript

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper

Is it possible to use stepper.reset() inside the ts file? I would like to do someting like

```
    onCheckRef() {
    if (this.refFormGroup.get('reference').invalid) {
      this.stepper.reset();
    } else {
      .....................
    }
  }
```

In the template :

```
<button mat-button (click)="onCheckRef()" matStepperNext>Valider</button>
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes You can access MatStepper Reference inside component using ViewChild decorator

First Define template reference variable in html using hash sympol

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
.....
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Then inside component use ViewChild decorator to access stepper instance

```
 @ViewChild('stepper',{read:MatStepper}) stepper:MatStepper;
```

Finally you can access reset method

```
onCheckRef() {
    if (this.refFormGroup.get('reference').invalid) {
      this.stepper.reset();
    } else {
      .....................
    }
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pptsbh?file=src/app/stepper-overview-example.ts)